# Is Emmet available specifically for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-generation, emmet

There are options for improving [HTML](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) and [CSS](http://sass-lang.com/) workflow but is it possible to do `Emmet` with `C#`?

We can **IMAGINE** it like this:

This **pseudo** Emmet code:

`if.interfaceName>cl.className>mtd.Main`

Generating this:

```
interface interfaceName{
    class className{
            void Main() {
            }
    }
}
```

I [looked up](https://www.google.com/search?q=Emmett+for+C#) but didn't found anything for **`C#` specifically**.

- Does anyone know about it?
- Any future possibilities?

Comment: I use emmet-vim to type emmet while editing C# code. There is an Emmet extension for Visual Studio https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/427e078e-4885-424b-8667-6485b7937145 , but I haven't used it.

Comment: @PaulOliver Sadly, it's for `HTML` and `CSS` not **`C#`** :(

Comment: what to do with `c#`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj Hang on, I'll put up an example to clarify your understanding, generate code from interface to classes

Comment: Sorry, I am still not clear about what you actually trying to do.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Look at the updated question

Comment: Do you want to generate template for c# code?

Comment: Yeah correct. `Emmet` does this only right?

Comment: @Student Well, now you're question is totally misunderstanding. But what I am reading is that you want to generate C# code using emmet, is that correct? Edit your question and state clearly that the code example is an example of how it SHOULD look like and not what it DOES look like.

Comment: @Jannik Is my question unclear?

Comment: Thanks, thats a bit better

Comment: There is concept called code snippet.
Please view the link below:

1.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42077/Code-Snippet-Step-by-Step-Guideline-from-Creation

2. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8af3e0/how-to-create-code-snippet-using-C-Sharp/

It will help you to generate c# code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In original Emmet (not the one used in VS, it uses its own implementation) you can create a [filter](http://docs.emmet.io/filters/) with a new syntax output. Emmet parses abbreviation into abstract tree and with filter you can walk on each node and generate custom output

Comment: This is insanely genius! I'm blindly marking this as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that concept is called as Code Snippet.
Please view following links. That may help you.

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42077/Code-Snippet-Step-by-Step-Guideline-from-Creation
2. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8af3e0/how-to-create-code-snippet-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: Sure, I'll go through both and post if I need some guidance.