# How to customize emmet filter for other languages, like C# or C?

Tags: c, code-generation, vscode-extensions, emmet

I was looking for a way to customize emmet to use my custom snippet in a function like way, and I have found a [post about it for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805033/is-emmet-available-specifically-for-c). Even though I have spend a time on it with vscode emmet configurations, I couldn't achieve it. In breif, can any body share their configuration about it, or explain how to do it in vscode?

Or any future customizable alternative for vscode such as [this vim plugin](https://github.com/jiangmiao/advancer-abbreviation).

Comment: Emmet is made for HTML and CSS, for other languages you can use other extensions from the extensions tab in vscode, you can also make custom [user snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets).

Comment: I know it and I did it already. However, if you look into link that I put they are telling other methods exist to change standart generation pattern of the emmet. Problem is that I could not how to. Besides, I have looked down into almost all code generation extention in vscode to find an alternative to emmet, and unfortunetly there is none, as far as I see. If you know one, I am completely open to advices.